# How to create a quality splash screen odd shaped like VS 2010?

Tags: winforms, graphics, .net-4.0, transparency, gdi

I've seen some neat splash screens like VS 2010, Adobe products, etc.  I know in VS.NET you can set a transparency color, etc. but I have never been able to make one look nice that didn't have some type of jagged edges or color issues on the edges.  For example, I could create a black circle with magenta as the transparent color and I've tried various aliasing options in Adobe PhotoShop CS4.

Can anyone steer me or provide an example of how to make a nice one like we see on VS 2010's startup?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

VS2010 runs as a WPF application.  WPF supports full alpha channel transparency, so the non-rectangular splash screens will always look better when using WPF than when using winforms.

I made the switch to WPF earlier this year solely based on the improved graphics capabilities.

Also in WPF, making a nice splash screen is dead easy.  Just create a nice .png in the shape you want with all your non-rectangular edges, anti-aliasing, and transparent background.  Then add this image to your project as a resource, and in the properties dialog box for that image, set its Build Action to 'SplashScreen'.  You're done.  Of course, that assumes that you make the switch to WPF.

Comment: This is not exclusive to WPF, winforms supports it too with the Form.TransparencyKey property.  VS2010 doesn't actually use WPF for the splash screen, it takes too long to get loaded.  The details are here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/11/11/behind-the-scenes-splash-screen.aspx  Layered windows is how both WPF and winforms implement the transparency.

Comment: @Hans Passant:  Good point.  Thanks for the link and clarification.  It is still much easier to do a high-quality splash screen in WPF than in winforms.

Comment: I don't think you know winforms well enough to make such a statement.  Especially in VB.NET where it requires *no* code at all.

Comment: This can be made in just few quick Win32 calls. No framework needed whatsoever (not even vc runtime). http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/09/displaying_a_splash_screen_with_c_introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that have some info on creating a splash screen

[SplashScreen Tutorial 1](http://www.codersource.net/microsoft-net/c-winforms/creating-a-splash-screen-in-c.aspx)

[SplashScreen Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swY1mkK-CrY&feature=related)

Although, these just explain how to make one and if I have understood correctly that you have jagged edges, I think that sounds more like the image is not very clear. Is the resolution high enough or are the edges pixelated and that is why they are jagged?